# Using Reactive Extensions to create a single event?

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to get my head around .NET Reactive Extensions, and I wonder if they can be used in the follow scenario:

In my WP7 app, I'm using the SterlingDatabase to persist app settings. As a user is modifying the settings, I want to periodically call `Database.Flush()`

So in my Property Set method, I'd like to kick off a Database.Flush() timer event, and in say 5 seconds, write to the database. If another property is written to, I want to restart the timer.

I know I can do this with a timer object, calling `Start()` and `Stop()`, but I wanted to know if I could do this with Rx, to create an Asycn operation that I can basically start and stop, without using a timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Throttle:

```
public void AttachFlushes(IObservable<Unit> writes, SterlingDb  db)
{
    writes.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Do(_ => db.Flush()).Subscribe();
}
```

Comment: The Do() isn't needed here. Just `Throttle().Subscribe(_ => db.Flush())` will work

Comment: Scott is right. But I also like the idea of side effecting in .Do and using parameter-less .Subscribe just to set the machine running. I think if developers would be constrained to only parameter-less Subscribes, it would help in RX understanding.